# Should I allow object to delete itself from its interface? Is it correct for OOD?

Tags: java, architecture, object, ooad

I have the following:

```
interface File
{ 
  String name();
  ...
}

interface FileService
{
  List<File> getAllFiles();
  ...
}
```

While working with the such interface If I decided to delete an entity represented by File instance (I mean to delete from a remote server), how should I do that?

Should I introduce `delete()` method for File interface (since it is Information Expert and possibly knows how to delete itself from the server)? Or should I delegate this function to it's creator -- `FileService` via `void deleteFile(File file)` interface method? And why?

If the first case is more appropriate how to invalidate the object to avoid its following using?

And related: how should I handle `uploadFile()` case? Who should be responsible for this? Because it seems that FileService will possibly violate SRP.

Thanks,

Comment: It depends.  It's not possible to say anything sensible about this without knowing a great deal more about your software architecture.

Comment: What is an "Informational Expert"?

Comment: *@Matti Virkkunen*: [Information_Expert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#Information_Expert) - I allowed myself to correct the question

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz: yes, I exactly meant GRASP's Information Expert, thank you for your correction.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: depends on what? `FileService` is a facade that provides access to the files stored somewhere (say on remote server). It will provide methods like: `uploadFile()`, `findFile(criteria)` etc. `File` i-face represent remote data. Hence common use-case: is to operate with the remote files, get statistics about them.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be on `File`.

If you have only one FileService (per connection to the server) which functions as the Factory of Files, you would probably want that service to keep up-to-date. You could then use something:

```
FactoryServiceImpl implements FactoryService {

    public File findFile(criteria) {
        return new FileImpl(this);
    }
}

// This should be package scope!
FileImpl implements File {
  private FactoryService service;

  // package scope!
  FileImpl(FactoryService service) {
      this.service = service;
  }

  public delete() {
      // invalidate this object - all calls should throw exception

      // Inform the service that this File should be deleted from
      // the server; or if the FileImpl does that itself, that the
      // FileService should update the cache of available files
      service.delete(this);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

There now is a cyclic dependency, which isn't great. The JVM can probably detect it and clean up any stuff, but you could also use a WeakReference.

It's a bit of a design choice whether you go with a thin factory and fact file, or the other way around. But they need to be able to communicate, as a file which is deleted through the factory should *know* it has been deleted.

Some code (assumes fact factory):

```
// This should be package scope!
FileImpl implements File {
  private Weakreference<FactoryService> serviceRef;

  // package scope!
  FileImpl(FactoryService service) {
      this.serviceRef = new WeakReference<FactoryService>(service);
  }

  public delete() {
      // invalidate this object - all calls should throw exception

      // Inform the service that this File should be deleted from
      // the server; or if the FileImpl does that itself, that the
      // FileService should update the cache of available files

      FactoryService service = serviceRef.get();
      if (service != null) {
          service.delete(this);
      }
  }
}
```

In this case I assume a fact factory as there is probably a network connection involved, and sharing a connection between multiple objects and threads tend to make the responsibility for closing that connection unclear.

This has as a consequence that the FactoryService interface should have a method `close()` or `dispose()` which terminates the connection and invalidates all the File's (as they are not accessible anymore).

**EDIT 2**

As far as OOD goes, I would probably try to mimic the java File API as far as possible. Thus, an object can be told to delete itself. Whether the implementation is in File or somewhere in FileSystem is not important (for the interface and the users of the class).

Comment: but in this way we get a cyclic dependency, doesn't we? I mean that `File` depends on its creator and we run into low coupling. I'd better to implement this like: `public FileImpl(Connection connection)... void delete() { Connection.sendRequest(...) }`. But the problem is I do not know who really should be responsible for file deletion.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it should be the FileService's responsibility. The reason and assumptions are

Assumption - Any object of file type represents a file that is retrieve from somewhere. It doesnt matter to the consumer. Fileservice implementation i believe, is the one that performs CRUD operations upon the file object. I also believe that Fileservice is more of file management concern. Therefore delete should be on the file service. 
If delete operation is present in the File object, then i believe file related operations are not cohesive and scattered across classes. Thats my opnion though. I would love to hear other opnions! BTW is the FILE class static in java?